# Create multiple instance like scala enum

Tags: scala, enums

The question is what do I need to do to replicate the functionality (for other class cooked on my own) of the scala enumerations:

```
val MY_ENUM_1, MY_ENUM_2 = Value
```

this creates 2 instances of `Value`. How can I do this for something like:

```
object App extends App {
    class Foo {}

    val foo1, foo2 = Foo

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `new` keyword:

```
scala> class Foo
defined class Foo

scala> val foo1, foo2 = new Foo
foo1: Foo = Foo@470e2030
foo2: Foo = Foo@3fb4f649
```

---

```
val MY_ENUM_1, MY_ENUM_2 = Value
```

works because it actually calls the method `Value` from `Enumeration`, which is:

```
/** Creates a fresh value, part of this enumeration. */
protected final def Value: Value = Value(nextId)
```

which will end up  calling

```
protected final def Value(i: Int, name: String): Value = new Val(i, name)
```

which in turn will return a `Val` (and also increment `nextId`).

You can see the whole process in the source code of [Enumeration](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/Enumeration.scala#L128) (starts line #128, the `Val` class is defined line #209).

Comment: Thanks I tried to see the source code but I was not able to find it... I am not familiar with where to find all the scala "stuff" yet

Comment: @Ordiel: Actually, in the Scala Docs, every Class/Trait/Object ([Enumeration](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Enumeration) for instance) has a link to its source code (right after the short description, before the examples), which is really handy.

Comment: Oh man thanks, that is going to help me a lot, let me try to find it